# Import JSON data into Python

Tags: python, json, file

Trying to find a simple way to import data from a JSON file into Python.  My initial thoughts would be to read the file line by line, but this might imply some additional processing which should already be done in a library.

The ideal solution would look something like:

```
import json_library

the_data = json_library.load_from_file('my_file.json')
```

where 'my_file.json' contains a JSON-formatted variable.

Comment: 2 upvotes, really? Where is the research effort? You'd expect someone with 2k rep to know how to search. This question is also not clear as it lacks an actual question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) will do that for you.

```
import json
data = json.load(open('my_file.json', 'r'))
```

Content of demo file:

```
{"hello":"stack overflow"}
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> print(json.load(open('my_file.json','r')))
{u'hello': u'stack overflow'}
```